# Copy Amazon Instance (windows) from US to EU

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I was asked to copy a current instance from US East (Virginia) to EU West (Ireland).

Looking online it seems that the best approach is to create an AMI (this was accomplished).

So now how do I transfer this Windows AMI into the EU West? How can I put it into the S3 buckets, and then turn it on? Is this possible for Windows AMIs?

A detailded explanition is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS just announced [Cross Region EC2 AMI Copy](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/03/ec2-ami-copy-between-regions.html)

> With EC2 AMI copy, you can easily copy the Amazon Machine Images
>   (AMIs) you own to other AWS regions and scale your applications to
>   take advantage of AWS's geographically diverse regions.

Here is the instructions from the user guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html?ref_=pe_12300_28673600_7

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using an ebs backed instance.

The bad news: as far as I know there is no easy way to do this.

The good news: it can be done. [Here](http://blog.ibd.com/scalable-deployment/copy-an-ebs-ami-image-to-another-amazon-ec2-region/) is a detailed walkthrough that addresses your problem. You will need to install the [ec2 command-line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351).

If your instance is without ebs you should be able to use the command-line tool ec2-migrate-image directly.

Comment: this article is for a linux instance.  ylastic.com list windows ebs ami transfer as a feature http://ylastic.com/features.html.  i'd bet they are doing something similar, but know some tricks for recreating the same bootable EBS in another region

Comment: the linked article uses `ec2-register` to create an AMI from a snapshot.  from the AWS documentation: "Registering a snapshot works only for Linux/UNIX AMIs; although you can register a snapshot to create a Windows AMI, the AMI isn't launchable." http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_LaunchingInstaceFromSnapshot.html